# After upgrading to Version 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB, why did the system reported connection error when using cli?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Please tell me how to solve this problem when I use Cli tool of Apache IoTDB to connect to the IoTDB database after upgrading the version to 1.2.2. The error message is `Connection Error: please check whether the network is available or the server has started. Host is 192.168.3.178, port is 6667`. I also tried to run jps in IoTDB, and the result looks like: `705 WrapperSimpleApp, 1116986 DataNode, 1128254 Jps`. I wonder if IoTDB has successfully started, and if not, how to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your jps results, seems like the cluster of Apache IoTDB did not start successfully. You can try to start seed ConfigNode first, then start all ConfigNodes, last start all DataNodes, and see if the whole system can be started.